# C# WinForms application showing many tray icons

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm super new to C# and this is my third question here regarding it.

I'm making an app which can be minimized to the system tray. I have two forms named `Form1` and `Form2`. What I have done so far is:

In `Form1`, I have a button which is showing the `Form2` using this code:

```
this.Hide();
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
```

The `Form2` has a button which is hiding it, using this code:

```
this.Hide();
```

Now, I have the tray icon on the task bar. The tray icon has a `ContexMenuStrip`, and there is an option named *show* using this code:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.Show();
```

The problem is that when I click on it, a second tray icon is appearing on the taskbar. Both tray icons have the same menu and both are working. If I click on *show* again another window with *Form1* pops up, and there are three tray icons, and so on....

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are creating a new Form1 everytime.

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

You don't want to create a *new* Form1, you want to show the old one. Give Form2 a reference to your *first* form1 (call it theMainform1 for example). And then instead of

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.Show();
```

You want to do

```
theMainform1.Show();
```

So you would have:

```
 this.Hide();
 Form2 form2 = new Form2();
 form2.theMainform1 = this;
 form2.Show();
```

Comment: How can I give reference? :'( I feel bad

Comment: Just like a I showed. Just add a property to Form2. E.g.,

//other properties of form 2
public Form1 theMainform1;

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you are making a new instance of Form1. This creates a brand new window instead of reviving your old one.

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    form1.Show();
```

You need to have Form2 reference the original instance of Form1. You can make a constructor to pass in a self reference that would look like

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent windows from having icons in the taskbar by settings ShowInTaskbar to false on the form.  However, the other answers are correct when they say you're creating a new form over and over.

Why would you want two forms to show at the same time?  Should they both be on the screen at the same time and be active at the same time?  If so, you might try a MDI interface.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface

It's possible in WinForms, but I think Microsoft is moving away from them in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code in case that someone is looking for it:

**Form1:**

```
/* Hiding Form1 and showing Form2 */    
private void btnHideForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {
                     Form mod = new Form2();
                     mod.Owner = this;
                     mod.Show();
                     this.Hide();
         }
```

**Form2:**

```
    /* Hiding Form2 and showing Form1 */
private void btnHideForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
                 this.Owner.Show();
                 this.Close();
         }
```

Thanks for your help guys!!!

I LOVE YOU!!!